# jquery: duplicate and paste html

Tags: jquery

hmm ok heres the shortened code

```
 <div id="SideCategoryList">
        <div class="BlockContent">
           <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Link A</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link B</a></li>
          </ul>
       </div>
     </div>
    <div id="navcont">
    <ul class="menu" id="menu">
      <li id="hov"><a href="#">Top Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Bottom Link</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
```

i want to use jquery to duplicate whats in the first ul into the first li in the #menu so it looks like this

```
<div id="SideCategoryList">
        <div class="BlockContent">
           <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Link A</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link B</a></li>
          </ul>
       </div>
     </div>
    <div id="navcont">
      <ul class="menu" id="menu">
         <li id="hov"><a href="#">Top Link</a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href="#">Link A</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Link B</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Bottom Link</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
```

so the finished product will be a 2 level list... let me know if this is makin sense lol

Comment: i know there is .clone().appendTo()  but i've been messing with it for like 2 hours

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#hov").append($(".BlockContent ul").clone());
```

Comment: nice one :) I was looking at it trying to figure out what the difference was in terms of browser interpretation/rendering.

Answer (score 1):

```
var content = $('#BlockContent').html();

$('#hov').append(content);
```

will append the `content` at the end of all the innerhtml of `$('#hov')`.

ie after the `<a href="#">Top Link</a>`.

hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this...

```
var copied_html = $('#BlockContent').html();
copied_html.insertAfter($('#menu li#hov a'));
```